# revision overriding the initial node created

Tags: 9, nodes

if using :

```
      $storage =\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
      $revision = $storage->load($nid);
      $revision = $revision->getTranslation($languageCode);
      $revision->setRevisionCreationTime(\Drupal::time()
        ->getCurrentTime());          
      $revision->save();
```

each new revision overrides the previous one.

There is no piles of revisions on the revision tab.

if using

```
      $storage =\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
      $revision = $storage->load($nid);
      $revision = $revision->getTranslation($languageCode);
      $revision->setRevisionCreationTime(\Drupal::time()
        ->getCurrentTime()); 
      $revision= $storage->createRevision($revision);         
      $revision->save();
```

Each revision is listed on the revision tab correctly.
But the two first revisions are identical

Comment: That is the expected behavior, since the second snippet is creating a new revision that is a duplicate of the existing revision, while the first snippet simply changes a revision property without creating a new revision. What don't you exactly understand, given those snippets?

Comment: @apaderno i am trying to have a code that create a new revision without affecting the previous revision

Comment: That is what the second snippet does. You get two identical revisions simply because nothing is changed in the entity object. To get two different revisions, you should change the title, for example, or the user who created the node.

Comment: this snippet is part of a module to edit paragraphs individually.i thought the snippet was causing the duplication, but thanks to u i figured out it was misplaced lines of code in that method